# generate Random uint64 between min and max

Tags: go, random

How can I generate a random 64 bit unsigned integer in Go?

First I need to call

```
rand.Seed(0)
```

and then I need a function that returns a uint64 with the following signature

```
func random(min, max uint64) uint64 {
}
```

The function above should return a random 64 bit unsigned integer in the
range [min, max] (min and max included)

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Int63n

Comment: @tkausl Int63n returns, as an int64, a non-negative pseudo-random number in [0,n) from the default Source. It panics if n <= 0,
so if max is max 64 bit integer it does not return it. Also it accepts a int not an unsigned it.

Comment: @gosom: Converting a uint64 to an int64 is trivial, and should be self-evident.

Comment: @gosom: for future reference, the question may have been better received if it wasn't worded as "here are my requirements, write my function for me". [ask]

Comment: @Flimzy yes it's trivial but still it does not include the max int as per documentation.

Comment: @gosom: What documentation? As far as I can tell, the function conforms to documentation exactly.

Comment: @Flimzy: The request is for a random function that can provide a distribution from `[0-max]` where `max<=MaxUint64`; while the `Int63n` function only covers `[0-max)` where `max<=MaxInt64`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are being downvoted. I think you are worried about the case where `max - min` is greater than MaxInt64 in which case `rand.Int63n` would fail as you have remarked. I would handle that case separately.

```
const maxInt64 uint64 = 1 << 63 - 1

func random(min, max uint64) uint64 {
    return randomHelper(max - min) + min
}

func randomHelper(n uint64) uint64 {
    if n < maxInt64 {
        return uint64(rand.Int63n(int64(n+1)))
    }
    x := rand.Uint64()
    for x > n {
        x = rand.Uint64()
    }
    return x
}
```

Comment: The question wants `[min,max]` but neither case in `randomHelper` includes the max value. I think you want something like https://play.golang.org/p/BLBwWklK7V